# Visual Studio 6.0 C++ GlobalMemoryStatusEx (Old SDK Needed)

Tags: c++, sdk, visual-studio-6, platform-sdk

I've inherited a C++ project whose code lives on an XP SP3 virtual machine (yay).

For some reason, even though afxwin.h is included (and I included winbase.h for good measure), when I compile the application, I get a bunch of errors, the root ones are:

```
error C2065: 'MEMORYSTATUSEX' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'GlobalMemoryStatusEx' : undeclared identifier
```

I found the structure definition on MSDN, so that solved part of my issue (even though this is defined in winbase, it's not coming through for some reason).

```
typedef struct _MEMORYSTATUSEX {
  DWORD     dwLength;
  DWORD     dwMemoryLoad;
  DWORDLONG ullTotalPhys;
  DWORDLONG ullAvailPhys;
  DWORDLONG ullTotalPageFile;
  DWORDLONG ullAvailPageFile;
  DWORDLONG ullTotalVirtual;
  DWORDLONG ullAvailVirtual;
  DWORDLONG ullAvailExtendedVirtual;
} MEMORYSTATUSEX, *LPMEMORYSTATUSEX;
```

But that still gives me the issue with GlobalMemoryStatusEx. I tried putting the function definition in the header, which then gave me an unresolved external symbol error.

```
WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI GlobalMemoryStatusEx( LPMEMORYSTATUSEX lpBuffer);

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall GlobalMemoryStatusEx(struct _MEMORYSTATUSEX *)" (__imp_?GlobalMemoryStatusEx@@YGHPAU_MEMORYSTATUSEX@@@Z)
```

Kernel32.lib is included in the compiler commands, so I'm not sure why this isn't working. I thought maybe the function was deprecated, however I can get this to run just fine in VS2013 on a Windows 7 machine, so it's not that. I think it has something to do with the fact that winbase isn't being recognized, but I haven't worked with C++ for 15 years, so I'm unsure where to start.

Any ideas?

**SOLUTION**

I doubt many people are interested in the solution, but here it is nonetheless!

I finally found the "Windows Server 2003 SP1 SDK" [in the Microsoft download center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15656) (a full list of SDKs is available [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK)). I then had to add directories to the Tools->Options within VS6.0, and move them to the top of the list.

And finally, I got to see `PROGRAM.exe - 0 error(s)`

[image: Options Menu]

Comment: VC6 predates the `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` function, which was introduced in Win2k, and so it is missing from the from the `kernel32.lib` import library shipped with it (for DLLs these are effectively static libraries with wrappers mapping to the dynamic functions). You'll either need an up-to-date library or dynamically locate the function via `GetProcAddress`. The latter option is probably more straightforward and would allow a fallback in the event that you are forced to support ancient systems with your ancient compiler.

Comment: I tried this. I downloaded a new version of the SDK however I must be changing the paths incorrectly, because it doesn't work (the appplication will not compile even basic applications). Can you point me at any documentation on how to do this? I've been unsuccessful in finding any.

Comment: It's hard to say without further information, the trick is finding an SDK version containing the function while still being compatible with VC6. The alternative approach is would be along the lines of `typedef BOOL WINAPI T(LPMEMORYSTATUSEX); T *p = (T *) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "GlobalMemoryStatusEx"); if(p) { /* Got it */ p(&status); }`

Comment: @doynax, how can you get MEMORYSTATUSEX data type with your approach?

Comment: @Dmitriy: The data type definition for the structure? You wouldn't. You'd manually copy the structure definition out of any modern SDK package or MSDN online documentation and include them directly into your project, and recursively grab any definitions which it may require. In the general case this can get messy, stripping off non-functional SAL annotations, massaging declarations incompatible with the compiler into forms generating an equivalent binary layout, translating COM interfaces into function pointer equivalents, etc. However, in this case it ought to be a simple copy-and-paste job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install an SDK that was released after VC 6 and that is new enough to include `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` but old enough to work with VC 6.

The SDK that is shipped with VC 6 is too old to include `GlobalMemoryStatusEx`.

Or, in my opinion the much better way: upgrade to a newer up-to-date version of Visual Studio (Visual Studio Express Editions can be downloaded for free.).

Comment: We tried this in the past with this code, however when moving to VS2010 or VS2013, several thousand errors happen during compile.